# How can I solve a log2N question where input size is doubled?

Tags: time-complexity

A method is O(Nlog2N). It takes .001 seconds for the method to run when N = 1,000.
What is the expected time for the method to run when N = 2,000?

I know the answer to the question is approximately 0.0022, but I don't know how to reach that answer. Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Since C(1000)=.001 and C(N) ~ k Nlog2N => k ~ .001 / (1000 * 10) ~ 1e-7
So C(2000) ~ 1e-7 * (2000 * 11) ~ .0022